# Visual Studio 'find all references' fails for event handlers?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, event-handling

Here is some simple sample C# code in Visual Studio 2008:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private static System.Timers.Timer TestTimer;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        TestTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        TestTimer.Elapsed += DoSomething;            
    }

   private void DoSomething(Object source, EventArgs e)
   {   

   }
}
```

If I right click on the `DoSomething` assigned as a handler, and select `Go to definition`, VS finds the body of `DoSomething`. So far so good.

If I Right Click on it and `Find all references` it finds nothing. (!?)

If I do either of these actions for the body of `DoSomething` itself, it finds only itself, not the assignment as an event handler.

Am I missing something obvious? A setting perhaps? In all other cases when you ask for `all references` that includes the definition and every other reference. I realize the assignment is thinking in terms of delegates, but this seems inconsistent.  It would be very convenient to easily find when something was assigned as a handler.

Comment: Have you rebuild your solution/Project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event handler declaration is not quite up to snuff.  The ElapsedEventHandler delegate has a different signature.  Fix:

```
    void DoSomething(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) {
       // etc..
    }
```

IntelliSense now will be able to find all references.  Do favor using IntelliSense to get the event assignment correct.  After you type `+=`, press the Tab key twice to let it automatically generate the code.

Comment: This is not code I was writing from scratch, but that I have inherited and am maintaining. It does compile and run as intended, just IntelliSense didn't. So apparently IntelliSense requires the full signature even if the compiler doesn't? Reasonable enough I suppose. Thanks!